# Why result of combining two hashMap is not corecct?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have two `HashMap`, first one has 3149 records and the second one 5440 records, when I combine them, the result size is smaller then 3149+5440. Why and how can i solve it?

```
Map<String,String> bigMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
bigMap.putAll(hashMap1);
bigMap.putAll(hashMap2);

int j = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : bigMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(j++);
}
```

**I also cheched with this code to be sure if there is some common key.**

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : readCsv(hashMap1).entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey(); 
    String value = entry.getValue();  
    if(entry.getKey().equals(hashMap2).get(key))){
        System.out.println(i++);
    } 
}
```

Comment: without the rest of your code it is difficult to say.  Are you positive of the record counts in both maps?

Comment: Smaller than 3149+5440, or smaller than 3149? If `hashMap1` and `hashMap2` share keys, only the `hashMap2` values for those keys will appear in `bigMap`.

Comment: Perhaps it's because hashMap1 and hashMap2 have some common keys?

Comment: Are you sure all keys are unique? You're basically doing a set union which results in a set with cardinality `A+B-Intersection(A,B)`.

Comment: **Smaller than 3149+5440** I cheched with this code to be sure if there is some common key.`for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : readCsv(hashMap1).entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
   if(entry.getKey().equals(hashMap2).get(key))){
    System.out.println(i++);
   }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `hashMap1` and `hashMap` probably have a number of same keys. That's why some entries are overridden by other entries with similar keys.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the same keys in the maps, then this is to be expected. Keys must be unique in a map. If you put a value into the map with a key that already exists, then the existing value is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

To find the common keys you can do

```
Set<String> common = new HsahSet<String>(hashMap1.keySet());
common.retainAll(hashMap2.keySet());
System.out.println("Common Keys " + common);
```